# click or tap not working in phantomjs via casperjs

Tags: jquery, phantomjs, casperjs

New to using `casper.js` and `phantom/js` been struggling getting click or tap event working on our Main page.

Below is the code I have been using. Submit form works and after that when I try to do a click or tap 
nothing works using phantomjs but same script with this line `this.evaluate(function() {$('#menuIcon').trigger('tap')});` works in `slimer.js`

I have tried different suggestion posted on stackoverflow and other sources and nothing is working any help appreciated !

```
/*==============================================================================*/
/* Casper generated Mon Aug 04 2014 23:04:32 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) */
/*==============================================================================*/
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
casper.options.viewportSize = {width: 1440, height: 900};
casper.options.clientScripts = ["includes/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"] 

// I've commented out CasperJS specific stuff, don't use it if you don't need it
function triggerEventOnPage(selector, eventName, memo) {
    casper.evaluate(function(selector, eventName, memo){
        var event;
        var element = document.querySelector(selector);
        event = document.createEvent("Event");
        event.initEvent(eventName, true, true);
        event.memo = memo || { };
        element.dispatchEvent(event);
        }, selector, eventName, memo);
        casper.wait(5000);
    }

    casper.on('page.error', function(msg, trace) {
        this.echo('Error: ' + msg, 'ERROR');
        for(var i=0; i<trace.length; i++) {
           var step = trace[i];
           this.echo('   ' + step.file + ' (line ' + step.line + ')', 'ERROR');
       }
    });
    casper.test.begin('Resurrectio test', function(test) {
       casper.start('url');
       casper.waitForSelector(".login_button",
           function success() {
               test.assertExists(".login_button");
               this.click('div.login_button');
           },
           function fail() {
               test.assertExists(".login_button");
       });
       casper.then(function success() {
            this.fillSelectors('form[name="f1"]', { 
                "input[name='login']": 'somevalue', 
                "input[name='passwd']": 'somepass'   
           },true,
           function fail() {
               test.assertExists("form[name=f1] input[type=submit][value='Sign in']")});
       });
       casper.wait(10000,
           function success() {
        this.capture('login.png');
        test.assertExists("#menuIcon");
        //tried this not working
        triggerEventOnPage("#menuIcon", 'tap');
        //tried this not working. Work in slimerjs
        //this.evaluate(function() {$('#menuIcon').on('tap', function(event){})});
        //this.evaluate(function() {$('#menuIcon').trigger('tap')});
        this.wait(5000);
        this.capture('CurrentScreen.png');  
       },
       function fail() { 
          test.assertExists("#menuIcon");
       });
       casper.wait(10000,
           function success() {
               //test.assertExists("#menu-1");
               //casper.evaluate(function() {$('#menu-1 > div.button.browseMovies').trigger('tap')});
        //this.wait(10000);
        //this.capture('CurrentScreen1.png');   
        },
        function fail() {
           test.assertExists(".button.browseTV.active");
        });
       casper.run(function() {test.done();}
 );}
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using casper.clickLabel as described in [API](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#clicklabel)

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.clickLabel('TextOnButton', 'ElementType');
});
```